# mimic pressing a button on a webpage in the backgroud, for triggering an action

Tags: iphone, ios

Pretend you have a button on an iOS GUI. Pressing this button should now trigger a button on a webpage (which triggers an action). While doing this, the webpage should not be visible. How can I do that?

My guess is, that I read and parse the webpage, and if I've found the button action, I would trigger it somehow. Since I'm not a web programmer, I wonder how to proceed or read on for such a task.

I need this task, because there is no JSON or XML webservice on the page that would make life easier.

Many thanks for any input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's say you've already loaded your webpage in an off-screen (or hidden) UIWebView, and the submit button on that webpage looked a bit like the following in code:

```
<form id="my_submit_button" etc... >
```

Just call the following:

```
NSString* javascript = @"document.forms['my_submit_button'].submit();";
[myUIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javascript];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Aha, this means I can trigger any action on a website that I can reach with Javascript?

Comment: Actions, textfields, etc, should all be fine yep.